# Two possible image paths, one fallback image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, onerror

I'm adding images to links dynamically by copying the link text to set the filename in src attr. If no image file matches the link text, a default image is displayed.

```
<a href="#">Argentina</a><br>
<a href="#">Brazil</a><br>
<a href="#">Colombia</a><br>
<a href="#">Peru</a><br>
<a href="#">Venezuelaaaaaaaaaa</a>
```

But the images (hundreds) can either be jpg or jpeg - how can I show x.jpg or x.jpeg and if neither found, show default.png? Can onerror be used a second time if *both* images fail to load?

```
$("a").each(function() {
$("<img>").insertBefore(this).attr("src", "https://www.sciencekids.co.nz/images/pictures/flags680/" + $(this).text() + ".jpg").on("error", function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "https://www.pocketfulofstones.co.uk/wp-content/themes/pocketful/img/ps_bottle_halo.png");
});
```

Or is there a better image fallback method when the filepath/filename is known, but the file extension can vary? Can src contain two URLs and display whichever is found? Multiple background images is not an option as the images have transparent parts.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3e67dpbr/)

Comment: You could use an if inside onerror to check if the current src ends with .jpg, jpeg, etc and set the src to the appropriate "next" file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using a separate function to determine what to try next...

```js
function tryNextImg(e) {
  if ($(e.target).attr('src').split(".").slice(-1)[0] == 'jpg') {
   // console.log(`try jpeg...`)
    $(e.target).attr('src', $(e.target).attr('src').replace('.jpg', '.jpeg'))
  } else {
   // console.log(`use default...`)
    $(e.target).attr('src', "https://www.pocketfulofstones.co.uk/wp-content/themes/pocketful/img/ps_bottle_halo.png");
  }
}

$("a").each(function() {
  let img = $("<img>").insertBefore(this);
  img.on('error', tryNextImg)
  img.attr("src", "https://www.sciencekids.co.nz/images/pictures/flags680/" + $(this).text() + ".jpg");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Argentina</a><br>
<a href="#">Brazil</a><br>
<a href="#">Colombia</a><br>
<a href="#">Peru</a><br>
<a href="#">Venezuelaaaaaaaaaa</a>
```

Comment: If these images are meant to be country flags, I'd rather download all of those images and save them using the same file extension. This will not only simplify your code, but it will improve your site's performance as those static files can be stored in a CDN, and you can save a lot of HTTP traffic overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I used country flags and jpg/jpeg as an example, but the images are actually sports team logos in either png or svg format.